# How to avoid object creation inside the onDraw method

Tags: android, performance, custom-view

I know that creating objects inside the `onDraw` method is very costly. I want to draw a matrix of rounded rectangles, which coordinates are dynamic, and I can't cache all that rectangles, because I use a scroll view and there may be a lot of rectangles, there's no other overload for `drawRoundRect` method, which has primitive arguments, and I forced to create a Rectangle object in every iteration. Who can suggest an effective solution for that?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int h = getMeasuredHeight();
    int tileSize = h / rows;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            int x = j * tileSize;
            int y = i * tileSize;
            canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x, y, x + tileSize, y + tileSize), 10, 10, tilePaint);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a just an example, rectangles can have arbitrary coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RectF` has the `set(left, top, right, bottom`) method. You could allocate it on the constructor and it this method to change the Rectf's bounds.

```
  mRect.set(x, y, x + tileSize, y + tileSize);
```

where mRect is `RectF mRect = new RectF();`

Comment: And almost all of the other objects you're likely to use in onDraw have some sort of reset method.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes very easy things are hard to guess :D

Comment: @mes you are welcome. As general rule, you should look the object's setter(s). It is usually possible to change the Object's mutable states without the need to allocate a new instance of that object